# sqlalchemy only apply filter if value is not None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on creating a sqlalchemy filter that looks for rows between a specific time-range, but I only want this filter to apply if they have a value for the day. If they don't not, they should also be returned. The filter looks like this:

```
 models = {
        CheckinAction: Student.person_id == CheckinAction.person_id,
        CheckinTimeRange: CheckinAction.chk_checkin_time_range_id == CheckinTimeRange.pk,
    }

    return join_models(query, models, "outerjoin").filter(
        CheckinTimeRange.day >= pendulum.parse(start_day).date(), CheckinTimeRange.day <= pendulum.parse(end_day).date()
    )
```

In the above code, the CheckinAction and CheckinTimeRange models are outerjoined onto an existing Student query. I'd like to only apply the CheckinTimeRange.day filter if they have a checkin action. An example would be:

```
row #1: {
student_id = 1,
student_name = 'row_to_not_filter',
checkin_action = None,
checkin_time_range = None
}

row #2: {
student_id = 2,
student_name = 'row_to_filter',
checkin_action = some_object,
checkin_time_range = {day = '2020-04-21'}
}
```

I'd like to only apply the filter to the second row because they have a checkin_time_range.

Comment: By "don't have a ...day value" you mean their day is NULL?

Comment: yeah. This filter is on a larger query that does an outerjoin on CheckinTimeRange. The fitler is filtering out where they have NULL for checkinTimeRange, but I'd like to return everything. Basically only want the filter to be applied if they have a timeRange.

Comment: That is important information, please edit the question to include that fact and a better example of the query. The reason being that in that case you could consider moving the predicate to the ON clause of the join.

Comment: Sure! I updated the question, does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a LEFT JOIN, move the predicate to the ON clause of the join:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

...
    models = {
        CheckinAction: Student.person_id == CheckinAction.person_id,
        CheckinTimeRange: and_(
            CheckinAction.chk_checkin_time_range_id == CheckinTimeRange.pk,
            CheckinTimeRange.day >= pendulum.parse(start_day).date(),
            CheckinTimeRange.day <= pendulum.parse(end_day).date()
        )
    }

    return join_models(query, models, "outerjoin")
```

Because `CheckinAction.chk_checkin_time_range_id` is used in the ON clause of the join to `CheckinTimeRange`, the `AND` will evaluate to NULL for row 1 and so achieves the result of not including the time range, if the action is missing. Moving the range predicate to the ON clause also achieves that rows with no range at all are included in the results.